# Taking the limit of a sine function?

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I take the limit of 
$$2\cdot\dfrac{\pi}{4n}\cdot \dfrac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\sin\left((n+1)\frac{\pi}{4n}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4n}\right)}$$

I'm not sure how it would be simplified to take the limit to eventually equal 1. Someone please explain so I can actually understand.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use $\,\displaystyle{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}\,$ and $\,\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1}$.

Let $\displaystyle{h=\frac{\pi}{4n}}$. Note $\displaystyle{n\to \infty\iff h\to 0}$.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(2\cdot \frac{\frac{\pi}{4n}}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4n}\right)}\cdot \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\cdot \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{4n}\right)\right)$$

$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\left(2\cdot \frac{h}{\sin\left(h\right)}\cdot \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\cdot \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+h\right)\right)$$

Comment: where the limit as n approaches infinity of sinx/x =1, does that work for the inverse of the expression as well or do I need to manipulate it further somehow ? Because now I can see that 2 * 1 * [sin(pi/4)]^2 = 1.

Comment: @saynomore I've edited it. You can change the variables. Now you just use the limit product rule directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can significantly reduce this expression with a bit of algebra. Use $$\sin(\pi/4) = \cos(\pi/4) =\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$ and $$\sin\left((n+1)\frac{\pi}{4n}\right) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{4n}\right) =  \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4n}\right)+ \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4n}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$ If I did my algebra correctly you'll get $$\frac{\pi\sqrt{2}}{4n}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{4n}\right)+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)$$ So if done correctly, you simply need evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{4n}\right)$. The rest is just coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Writing the original expression as
\begin{equation*}
2\cdot \dfrac{\pi }{4n}\cdot \dfrac{\sin \left( \frac{\pi }{4}\right) \sin
\left( (n+1)\frac{\pi }{4n}\right) }{\sin \left( \frac{\pi }{4n}\right) }%
=2\cdot \sin \left( \frac{\pi }{4}\right) \cdot \sin \left( \left( \frac{n+1%
}{n}\right) \frac{\pi }{4}\right) \cdot \frac{\left( \frac{\pi }{4n}\right) 
}{\sin \left( \frac{\pi }{4n}\right) }
\end{equation*}
and using standard limits 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x}{\sin x}=1,\ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \ \
\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty }\frac{n+1}{n}=1
\end{equation*}
then
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty }2\cdot \dfrac{\pi }{4n}\cdot \dfrac{\sin \left( 
\frac{\pi }{4}\right) \sin \left( (n+1)\frac{\pi }{4n}\right) }{\sin \left( 
\frac{\pi }{4n}\right) }=2\cdot \sin \left( \frac{\pi }{4}\right) \cdot \sin
\left( \frac{\pi }{4}\right) \cdot 1=2\cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cdot \frac{%
\sqrt{2}}{2}\cdot 1=1.
\end{equation*}